# deleting foreign key child record error 547

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a Table `Task` with `TaskId` as Primary Key. And another table `TimeSheet` with `TaskId` as foreign key. I created foreign key relation like this

```
ALTER TABLE TimeSheet ADD CONSTRAINT fk_TimeSheet_TaskId FOREIGN KEY(TaskId)
REFERENCES Task (TaskId)
GO
```

Actually, if I try to delete (or update) a row in Task table it should show an error regarding foreign key relation. And if I try to delete in `TimeSheet` table I should not get any error.

But for me I am getting the 547 error if I try to delete or update in `TimeSheet` table.
Nulls are allowed in Foreign Key column (`TaskId` in `TimeSheet` Table).

What should I do here? I want to throw error if I try to delete or Update in parent table (`Task`) and No error if I try to delete or update in child table (`TimeSheet`).

Comment: Are you able to show us the definitions of both tables including all the constraints?

Comment: Also, the title of this question is not the real error is it? Can you copy and paste the exact error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use FOREIGN KEY:

Whenever rows in the master (referenced) table are deleted (resp. updated), the respective rows of the child (referencing) table with a matching foreign key column will get deleted (resp. updated) as well. Not vice-verse.

If you want to work as per your question try to use trigger.

Comment: That's not what the OP's trying to do, and deleting a row containing a foreign key to another table should not normally cause any issues.